# Is there a difference between Therefor and Therefore?

Tags: orthography

I'm a non-native English speaker, and my automatic spellchecker seems to accept both therefore and therefor. Is one orthography preferred ? Is that a British vs. American difference ? Or an old vs. more recent orthography ? Or something else ?

Comment: You could look it up: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefor

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Therefor** means *for that*.

For example:

> Here we sell guitars and accessories therefor.

*Therefor* is one of a whole series of adverbs: *thereof* (of that), *thereafter*(after that), *therein* (in there), etc.

If you are familiar with German - the Germanic sister of English -  you can find a direct analogy there:

> for = für
>
> therefor, for that = dafür (literally, therefor)

**Therefore**, as you must know, means *as a (logical) consequence*

Comment: +1: that's the only way I could make sense of dafür, davon, darauf, etc. in German class

Answer (score 27):

**Therefore** and **therefor** are completely different words.

Therefor, an archaic word, means  "for this", "for that", or "for it". E.g;

> ... ordering goods and enclosing payment therefor.

Therefore means "for that reason" or "hence".E.g;

> Those people have their umbrellas up: therefore, it must be raining

Comment: I wouldn't say *therefor* is archaic. Its usage is not uncommon, especially in legal documents.

Comment: This answer explains the difference more directly than Armen's answer.

Comment: [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/therefore-vs-therefor/) says it is both Archaic and now relegated mainly to Legalese (which we all know are usually templated documents written ages ago that have withstood legal scrutiny for decades and we continue to reuse and edit to fit our specific needs).  If something has fallen out of the common lexicon we use to communicate with and phrases like "for this", "for that", and "for it" already exist that make more sense to those still living (and use the same amount of characters or less), then I'd argue that "therefor" is indeed Archaic.