# Why is therefore not written therefor?

Tags: etymology, orthography, old-english, prepositions

Having [just learned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fore-) that in Old English the word *for* was written as *fore*, why is *therefore* still written as it is currently, and not as *therefor*?

Being a non-native English speaker, many times I automatically write *therefor*, as my brain probably is thinking on *for*. Alternatively, many times I also write *fore*, as my brain is probably thinking on *therefore*.

Edit: the [possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58616/is-there-a-difference-between-therefor-and-therefore) is about the difference between the two expressions, and it would only be relevant if the actual reason why it is *therefore* instead of *therefor* is to distinguish them. But since that is not the reason, I believe that question is not a duplicate of this.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58616/is-there-a-difference-between-therefor-and-therefore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "fore" in therefore does not mean "for". It means

- situated or placed in front
- the front part of something

That same root is used in words like

- before, aforementioned, foreboding, etc.

I don't suppose you are proposing to change the spelling of all these words?

The word "therefor" does use "for" [and means "for that"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58616).

P.S. When you thing about it, the German cognate of "fore" is "vor", and the one for "for" is "für".

Comment: Good explanation Armen, although I wonder the root of 'forward'? Should it be 'foreward'?

Comment: @Pete855217 - ***Forward:***
*Old English forewearde "toward the front, in front; toward the future; at the beginning;" see fore + -ward. ---- 
***Fore***. - mid-15c., "forward;" late 15c., "former, earlier;" early 16c., "situated at the front;" all senses apparently from fore- compounds, which frequently were written as two words in Middle English.

Comment: Ahah well there you go, thanks Josh61 that was enlightening!

Comment: Isn't your answer at odds with [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=therefore)? **therefore (adv.):** Old English þærfore; from there + fore, Old English and Middle English collateral form of for. Since c. 1800, therefor has been used in sense of "for that, by reason of that;" and therefore in sense of "in consequence of that." Similar formation in Dutch daarfoor, German dafür, Danish derfor.

Comment: @Jacinto I don't know about Dutch or Danish, but dafür in German means "therefor", not "threrefore"

Comment: My main issue is with: from *there* + *fore*, Old English and Middle English collateral form of *for*. Etymolyne also says *therefor* is a "Middle English variant spelling of *therefore*"

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան _Derfor_ in Danish means both ‘therefore’ and ‘therefor’; as in German, only one of the possible combinations exist (there is no _*derfør_). The extended and unextended forms of this preposition/adverb are thoroughly enough mixed up in all the Germanic languages that it doesn't really make sense to say that _fore = vor_ and _for = für_. As Etymonline states, _therefor(e)_ is one word with two alternative spellings that eventually became two words through increasingly distinct usage—the _fore_ in it really does mean ‘for’. The word makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED45166&egs=all&egdisplay=open